# Denying access via .htaccess according to referrer

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I'm trying to block access to my website depending on whether a visitor had visited the site through another website. The latter has been using up my traffic by using an iframe to display content through his site, masking my site's identity.

I have *mod_env_if* activated in apache2.

```
ErrorDocument 403 /error403.html
SetEnv noaccess=0
SetEnvIf Referer "^http://sitetoblock\.tk/" noaccess=1
SetEnvIf Referer "^http://www\.sitetoblock\.tk/" noaccess=1


<FilesMatch "\.(gif|png|jpe?g|php|html)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from env=noaccess

</FilesMatch>
```

The problem is that this directive is blocking all traffic including direct visitors to the site. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [In the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) they sometimes omit the quotes in their examples. Maybe give it a try? Also, why the last forward-slash after "tk"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your configuration, default access state is "Deny" because you have "Order Allow,Deny". 
Change the Order to "Deny, Allow" so you can explicitly deny access based on your referer check.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape out the dots in the urls, like:

```
SetEnvIf Referer "^http://sitetoblock\.tk/" noaccess=1
SetEnvIf Referer "^http://www\.sitetoblock\.tk/" noaccess=1
```

Comment: I escaped the periods, but it still denies access to everyone. Qn edited.